# Why won't my armature move when I append it to another .blend?

Tags: armature, pose-mode

I rigged a model and the armature moves fine in the .blend I have it in. However, when I transfer it to another blend file I can only move it through the pose library, not through pose mode.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Also, I checked to make sure none of the bones were improperly parented to each other

Comment: Are you certain that you appended it and not linked it?